# How to mock a function that returns a value class instance with Mockito?

Tags: scala, mockito, value-class

I'm trying to mock a method that returns an instance of a value class (`extends AnyVal`)
I'm getting some weird error message, which I understand (because of value class erasure) but I'm surprised Mockito doesn't cope with that.

My class:

```
case class MyValueClass(value: String) extends AnyVal
```

The function I want to mock:

```
trait ToMock {
  def something(someParams: String): MyValueClass
}
```

And the mock:

```
val theMock = mock[ToMock]
val returned = MyValueClass("test")
when(theMock.something("test")).thenReturn(returned)
```

This code generates the following error:

```
MyValueClass cannot be returned by something()
something() should return String
```

But of course, if I make it return a String, it doesn't compile anymore...

If I remove `extends AnyVal`, of course it works fine.

Comment: Mockito gives "zip" about your Scala types. I would use javap to understand the *true* signature of that method by checking the content in the bytecode files first. To be really sure that your scala-perception matches the content that Mockito is using to make its decisions.

Comment: That's the problem: to compile, Scala needs MyValueClass, but of course because it's a value class, it's erased on byte code, so at runtime, mockito wants the wrapped value (a String in my example). I'm only looking for a workaround.

Comment: Found a way, see my answer below

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Good to remember that one can "cheat out" of such problems this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found an answer that works.
I need to use the older mockito style of `doReturn`

```
doReturn(returned.value).when(theMock).something("test")
```

Because it's not type-safe, it works. 
Not fully satisfactory though, as I give up type safety.